# Why can't I pass a regex in @ARGV on the command line?

Tags: command-line, regular-expression, perl, arguments

Why can't I use `if($l =~ $ARGV[0])` but I can use `if($l =~ /$ARGV[0]/g`?

**first case**

```
$ perl script.pl '/^[\w]/g'
```

**second case**

```
$ perl script.pl '^[\w]'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings and regexes are different primitive types in perl, and all variables placed in the `@ARGV` array are simply strings given to the program by the kernel at startup; `$ARGV[0]` is a scalar string, and not a regex.

When you do `if($l =~ $ARGV[0])` and `$ARGV[0]` is `'/^[\w]/g'` this is equivalent to `if($l =~ '/^[\w]/g')` instead of `if($l =~ /^[\w]/g)`. In the former case the slashes are simply characters in a string while in the later they are a part of the Perl syntax that delimits a regular expression.

Comment: To work around this, you can use `$regex = qr{$ARGV [0]}`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice guys. Could you take a look at this question mentioning other error in the same script? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249368/regex-through-argv0-not-entering-the-if-statment